# how to create /proc file inside kernel module?

Tags: c, file, linux-kernel, filesystems, proc

I want to save some information in a kernel module. I have seen similar question to mine here in stackoverflow, however mine is slightly different. Assuming I am using [this code](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x769.html) to write in a /proc file. How should I call it inside one of my kernel module? I have a custom kernel module called `mymodule` which is not the main file (does not have init_module()) inside it the below function is called. In this case what should be the input value to the function like value of `file`? Basically is it possible to create a /proc file inside a kernel module?

`int procfile_write(struct file *file, const char *buffer, unsigned long count,
           void *data)`

Comment: Try looking at how the other drivers use /proc entries.  You can query your driver via user space by reading (via cat or whatever) that entry from the command line.  You can also write to your driver if the proc write() method is implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is definitely possible to add a proc entry in a kernel module but you might be misunderstanding how file handling works in the kernel.

When you create a file in proc, you're not actually 'creating' a file like you would in userspace. You're registering a few callbacks that are called when userspace programs request your file.

That means, when userspace programs request a read, your file read callback has to provide data. When a userspace program requests a write, your file write callback has to handle it.

If you want to use it like a conventional file to store information, you have to allocate the required space and have your read callback copy data from there.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I want to store some information inside the LKM. Sorry I'm new to it. How should I "allocate the required space and have  read callback copy data from there"?

Comment: Well that depends. You could use `kmalloc` or `vmalloc` to allocate the space you need then store a pointer to it somewhere where your `procfile_read` callback can find it.